# polynomial interpolation error; is it continuous?

Tags: lagrange-interpolation

Let $f$ be a $n+1$-times continuously differentiable function on the interval $[a,b]$, and let $p_n$ be the $n$th degree Lagrange interpolation polynomial, defined by
$$
p_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^nL_i(x_i)f(x_i),
$$
where
$$
L_k(x)=\prod_{i=0,i\neq k}^n\frac{x-x_i}{x_k-x_i},
$$
for given $x_i\in[a,b]$.
The error is given by
$$
f(x) - p_n(x) = \frac{f^{n+1}(\xi(x))}{(n+1)!}\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i).
$$
I was wondering how one could show that $\xi(x)$ is a continuous function? I need that for another theorem about numerical integration. I am familiar with the proof of the interpolation error, which is basically just applying Rolle $n+1$ times, using an auxiliary function. But how to show continuity of $\xi(x)$ from there on, I don't know. Any ideas?